# Como usar terraform import con un Modulo

Tags: azure-storage, terraform

Buen dia a todos.
Estoy importando recursos desde azure a mi proyecto de terraform con el siguiente script como ejemplo:

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.migrations_rg /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/TEST-Fuse-Migrations-azf-rg
```

Todo esta funcionando correctamente pero me pidieron cambiar la estructura de los folder y usar un modulo, por lo que mi estructura final quedo de la siguiente manera:

Infrastructure
--Terraform
----Enviroments
------Test
--------maint.tf
----Modules.tf
------maint.tf

en el archivo main.tf dentro de Modules tengo los recursos que se comparten entre los ambientes y dentro del archivo main.tf de cada ambiente tengo el siguiente codigo para utilizar el modulo:

```
module migrations_azf_stage{
    source = "../../Modules"

    environment_name = "stage"
    storageAccounts_pdcodacpacoutput_name = "pdcodacpacoutputstage"
    storageAccounts_pdcomigrations_name =  "pdcomigrationsstage"
}
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es que el import no funciona, marca el siguiente error en la consola al por ejemplo, ejecutar el import para el resource_group

```
Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "migrations_rg" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

Terrafom init, validate y plan funcionan correctamente. Debo mencionar que todos los comandos (init, validate, plan y apply) los estoy ejecutando dentro de la carpeta TEST y en el Modulo solo ejecute terarform init

Agradezco su ayuda en como ejecutar el import de terraform con el module

Answer (score 0):

Estuve investigando y es muy simple poder utilizar imports con un modulo, solo es necesario añadir module.nombre_del_modulo. Siguiendo mi ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

terraform import **module.migrations_azf_stage**.azurerm_resource_group.migrations_rg /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/TEST-Fuse-Migrations-azf-rg

Answer (score 0):

Que no es un move lo que necesitas? `terraform state mv <src> <dest>`

Para saber el path del destino realiza un cambio y un plan sin apply para ver el path del recursos por crear. `terraform plan` y ponerlo en el commando anterior.